# When mapping a domain with `hosts` file, Node requires the WSL IP, but Vite requires 127.0.0.1

Tags: networking, localhost, wsl2, node.js

I'm on Windows 10 developing in WSL2/Ubuntu-20.04. I create a basic Node+Express server:

`npm init -y; npm i express`

```js
// index.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

I `curl http://localhost:3000/` from Windows and WSL/Ubuntu, and both work! Sweet.

I add `127.0.0.1 foobar.com` to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and restart WSL with `wsl --shutdown`, causing `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-20.04\etc\hosts` to regenerate. I `curl http://foobar.com:3000/`. It succeeds in WSL/Ubuntu, but fails in Windows with `curl: (7) Failed to connect to foobar.com port 3000 after 2040 ms: Connection refused`. I find this surprising because I've been building a [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) app and updating my `hosts` file works there. (I've been testing with `npm create vite@latest` for the purposes of this question.)

After much head-scratching, I discover that using my WSL IP address in my `hosts` file (e.g. `172.31.230.172 foobar.com`, discovered using `wsl hostname -I`) allows me to hit my Node server from Windows. However, this change breaks my Vite apps with the same error message as the earlier Node problem.

Here's a table summarizing my symptoms.

| Code | Hosts | URL | Windows | WSL/Ubuntu |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Node | N/A | `http://localhost:3000/` | ✅ | ✅ |
| Vite | N/A | `http://localhost:5173/` | ✅ | ✅ |
| Node | `127.0.0.1 foobar.com` | `http://foobar.com:3000/` | ❌ | ✅ |
| Vite | `127.0.0.1 foobar.com` | `http://foobar.com:5173/` | ✅ | ✅ |
| Node | `172.30.206.133 foobar.com` | `http://foobar.com:3000/` | ✅ | ✅ |
| Vite | `172.30.206.133 foobar.com` | `http://foobar.com:5173/` | ❌ | ❌ |

Ideally, I'd like to use `127.0.0.1 foobar.com` in my `hosts`, since my WSL IP might change. I'm not too picky though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my Node code should include a hostname:

```
app.listen(port, "127.0.0.1", () => {...}
```

I've no idea why this works. An explicit `0.0.0.0` also works.

[The Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#serverlistenport-host-backlog-callback) states

> If `host` is omitted, the server will accept connections on the unspecified IPv6 address (`::`) when IPv6 is available, or the unspecified IPv4 address (`0.0.0.0`) otherwise.

My experience here, however, does not support this. For my machine, the hostname must be explicitly 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0. I'm not the only one - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68768804) also asks why the hostname is required in Node to make the `hosts` file mapping work. Please answer there if you know!

Comment: I totally thought this was a networking question, hence asking it here, but it turned out to be a programming issue. Argh.